# Call function or pass data to another controller AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I already have seem other topics with this kind of issue, but no one could help me... So here is my issue:

I have a navbar with a button for search, this buttons makes and get request from a webservice and returns a json object which must be apply to fill an table list. The problem is, my button and my table are in separated controllers, and it does work like I expected.

```
var app = angular.module('clientRest', []).controller('lista', ['$scope', 'loadLista', function($scope, loadLista) {
    $scope.contatos = loadLista.getContatos();
}]).controller('pesquisa', ['$scope', '$http', 'loadLista', function($scope, $http, loadLista) {
    $scope.listar = function() {
        $http.get("http://localhost/wsRest/index.php/contato").success(function(response) {
            loadLista.setContatos(response);
        });
    };
}]).service('loadLista', function() {
    var contatos = [];
    return {
        getContatos: function() {
            return contatos;
        },
        setContatos: function(c) {
            contatos = c;
        }
    };
});
```

My code...
When I call `listar()` from pesquisa controller I need to send received data to $scope.contatos from lista controller to make my ng-repeat work, everything with a single click.

How can I do it?

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $rootScope.$emit to emit a change event when setting the variable and use $on to get the value in the lista controller. I used customListAr here just to demostrate a button click. Does this help?

```js
var app = angular.module('clientRest', [])
  .controller('lista', ['$scope', 'loadLista', '$rootScope',
    function($scope, loadLista, $rootScope) {
      console.log(loadLista);
      $scope.contatos = loadLista.getContatos();
      $rootScope.$on('change', function() {
        $scope.contatos = loadLista.getContatos();

      });
    }
  ])
  .controller('pesquisa', ['$scope', '$http', 'loadLista',
    function($scope, $http, loadLista) {
      $scope.listar = function() {
        $http.get("http://localhost/wsRest/index.php/contato").success(function(response) {
          loadLista.setContatos(response);
        });

      };

      $scope.customListAr = function() {
        loadLista.setContatos(["item 1" , "item 2", "item 3"]);
      }
    }
  ])
  .service('loadLista', ['$rootScope',
    function($rootScope) {
      var contatos = [];
      return {
        getContatos: function() {
          return contatos;
        },
        setContatos: function(c) {
          contatos = c;
          $rootScope.$emit('change');
        }
      };
    }
  ]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="clientRest">
  <div ng-controller="lista">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="a in contatos">{{a}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div ng-controller="pesquisa">
    <button ng-click="customListAr()">Click Me</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Better to use a service to share data between two controllers / modules as this might be the best approach. You can refer the code segment given below to understand the concept.

```
angular.module('app.A', [])
.service('ServiceA', function() {
    this.getValue = function() {
        return this.myValue;
    };

    this.setValue = function(newValue) {
        this.myValue = newValue;
    }
});

angular.module('app.B', ['app.A'])
.service('ServiceB', function(ServiceA) {
    this.getValue = function() {
        return ServiceA.getValue();
    };

    this.setValue = function() {
        ServiceA.setValue('New value');
    }
});
```

In order to trigger the data receipt event, you may use

1. Broadcast / emit messages - with `@broadcast` / `@emit`
2. An angular promise with a call back
3. Controller initiation function to reload the previously read information from a service

   `.controller('MyController', function($scope, ServiceA) {
      $scope.init = function() {
         $scope.myValue = ServiceA.getValue();
      };
      // Call the function to initialize during Controller instantiation
      $scope.init();
   });`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that when you do $scope.contatos = loadLista.getContatos(); you are setting a static value, and angular is unable to effectively create a watcher for that object because your setContatos method is creating a new object each time.  To get around this, have the controller's scope hold a reference to the parent object and then it will automatically have a watcher on that object.

```
var app = angular.module('clientRest', [])
    .controller('lista', ['$scope', 'loadLista', function($scope, loadLista) {
        $scope.contatos = loadLista.contatos;
    }])
    .controller('pesquisa', ['$scope', '$http', 'loadLista', function($scope, $http, loadLista) {
        $scope.listar = function() {
            $http.get("http://localhost/wsRest/index.php/contato"
            ).success(function (response) {
                loadLista.contatos.data = response;
            });
        };
    }])
    .service('loadLista', function() {
        var lista = {
            contatos: {},
        };
        return lista;
    });

// view:

<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="contato in contatos.data">
    {{ contato }}
  </li>
</ul>
```